# Can [meta-tag:advanced-search] be made a synonym for [meta-tag:search]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, meta

I noticed that we have two different meta tags for "search" questions:

- [search](/questions/tagged/search)
- [advanced-search](/questions/tagged/advanced-search)

These are analogous to the same meta tags (or just tags?) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Can `[advanced-search]` be made into a synonym for `[search]`? I see no reason why we need both. "Advanced search" questions are just plain search questions.

#### The numbers

Here on MSO, there are currently [31 questions tagged with `[search]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/search/synonyms), and [24 questions tagged with `[advanced-search]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/advanced-search/info).

#### Voting

So I kind of jumped the gun a little (it's my first time creating a tag synonym), and I've already [started the synonym proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/search/synonyms). People just need to vote on it.

So vote please...pretty please, with a cherry on top?

[image: Cherry cupcake]

<sub>[Cherry Bomb Cupcake](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sbogdanich/8473812572/) by Stephanie, from [Capital City Bakery](http://www.capitalcitybakery.com/) (Austin, Texas).</sub>

Comment: Bad Cupcake! Now you've gone and spoiled the beautiful [list of my name](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)!

Comment: @VotetoClose just be glad you got a cupcake at all `:P`