# Rename [git-bare] to [git-bare-repository]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

There are currently [80 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bare?sort=newest) tagged with [[git-bare]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-bare/info), to explain the concept of bare repositories in Git. Can this tag be renamed to [git-bare-repository] please?

[git-bare] is a little vague, while [git-bare-repository] clearly describes what "bare" refers to. [[git-rewrite-history]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-rewrite-history/info) is another tag used for questions that involve a Git concept, rather than a Git command.

Additionally, [git-bare] can be confused with a Git command (that doesn't exist), because there are similarly named tags that *are* actual commands, such as [[git-push]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-push/info), [git-merge], [git-clone], etc.

[image: Anyone want some cupcakes?]
<sub>Random cupcake cropped and resized from [Homemade Agave Sweetened Marshmallow Topped Cupcake](https://www.flickr.com/photos/clevercupcakes/3245006293).</sub>

Comment: @Will I didn't use the `tag:` syntax because it messes up the vertical spacing between lines. Now my question look like one very ugly duck `:P`. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Do you know how annoying it is when someone asks about specific tags but then doesn't provide an easy way to get to that tag in order to view its wiki or questions?  Do you???  *Do you???*

Comment: @Will [I already provided a link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-bare/info) to the relevant wiki for the tag in question. Do you think I should add links to the other tags as well?

Comment: ***LINK ALL THE TAGS!*** ... eh, would be nice, as you are talking about them.

Comment: @Will [I updated some more links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/267246/5).

Comment: What in the world is with the cupcake in the question? Am I missing something (other than OPs username)?

Comment: @StevenV [Will was being a ***BIG MEANIE***](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267246/rename-git-bare-to-git-bare-repository?noredirect=1#comment70002_267246), so I wanted a cupcake to cheer me up. Plus, didn't you know that [requests that contain cupcakes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266113/456814) have a [100% higher chance of being approved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236788/163250)?

Comment: +1 because cupcake ... I might just read this post while I'm here.